# Django form redirect after POST is unreliable and needed a success_url

Tags: python, django-forms, http-post, django-class-based-views

I am totally stuck to understand this behaviour and found a workaround I don't really like.  Can anyone help enlighten me please?  The context is I have a bootstrap styled form to create new records (inheriting from the generic.CreateView)

url.py:

```
url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
url(r'^main/$', views.MainView.as_view(), name='MainView'),
url(r'^topic/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', catalogue_views.TopicView.as_view(), name='TopicView'),
url(r'^resource/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', catalogue_views.DetailView.as_view(), name='ResourceDetail'),
url(r'^contribute/$', catalogue_views.ContributeView.as_view(success_url="/main/"), name='Contribute'),
```

views.py:

```
class ContributeView(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = "openeye/contribute.html"
    form_class = ContributeForm

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ContributeView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class MainView(generic.ListView):

    template_name = "openeye/main.html"
    context_object_name = 'topic_list'

    # TODO Make this only active topic areas?
    def get_queryset(self):
        return TopicArea.objects.all().order_by('name')

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MainView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py:

```
class ContributeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CatalogueItem
        fields = ['title', 'topic_area', 'description', 'link', 'what_learn', 'how_apply', 'level', 'relevant_to', 'discovered_by']

    ROLE_CHOICES = [[x.id, x.job] for x in JobType.objects.all()]

    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'To sell this resource to others'}), max_length=80, required=True)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 2, 'placeholder': 'Clear, e.g. format, duration, activities...'}))
    link = forms.CharField(widget=forms.URLInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'If required, link to resource http://...'}), required=False)
    what_learn = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3, 'placeholder':"This is important,."}), label='What will you learn?')
    how_apply = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3, 'placeholder':"How could this be put into action afterwards?"}), label='How could you apply this?')
    relevant_to = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
```

and a template with a form:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="entry-form row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                <form action="{% url 'MainView' %}" method="post" class="form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
                    {% bootstrap_form form %}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Submit Suggestion</button>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The form works perfectly and the data is saved nicely into the database.  The problem is afterwards, the browser goes to the correct URL /main/ but the SCREEN IS BLANK.  The server shows HTTP 405 0, and if I refresh the page it works.

If I alter the template so the action="{% url 'Contribute' %}" to return to the same form, I get HTTP 500 and a Django message about 'No URL to redirect to'.  So two different errors determined by the re-direct location.  In both case if I just click in browser url field and hit return it works.

I am sure this worked initially and then broke but I solved it as follows.  Hard code in the success_url using it's path

```
url(r'^contribute/$', catalogue_views.ContributeView.as_view(success_url="/main/"), name='Contribute'),
```

Removing any action link in the template:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form">
```

Is this the correct approach?  Why, despite going to the correct URLs, do the pages not load or give errors with my original approach?  I'd love to understand this.

Comment: Servers shows 405 on `/main/`? Can you post the code of the `MainView` then?

Comment: Sure I added it.  /main. calls a ListView that acts as a main page menu for the site.  The form action can go to any page and get the same effect, it does not seem to be view specific.

Comment: Thanks, it was for checking whether you had any handling of form of post method in the main view, that would have changed my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your data is actually saved on the server? From what you posted, it seems very unlikely. Here is the normal process followed by Django:

1. GET on form view (ContributeView)
     → returns an empty form
2. POST on form view (ContributeView)
     → if invalid, go back to step 1. If valid return a `302 Redirect` to `success_url`.
3. GET on success_url

So normally, in your template, the form action should be empty, so the form gets posted back to the view that generated it. And the `ContributeView` should have a success url that redirects to wherever you want to send the user after:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
class ContributeView(generic.CreateView):
    # other stuff
    success_url = reverse_lazy('MainView')
```

The behavior you get, with the 405, is because the browser, attempts to send the form directly to `MainView` which, not being a form view, tells the browser it does not know how to handle a `POST` method.

Comment: Thank you, it works :)  Records always saved in the database 100% of the time despite the errors.  Anyway, I added the success_url to my class as above.  Perfect.  Now off to learn more about reverse_lazy...

Comment: That's odd, but if your problem is solved, I don't feel like taking the time to understand how comes it was saving anyway. Glad you could make it work. By the way, `reverse_lazy` is just the same as `reverse`, except the actual computation of the url is deferred until it is actually used. It's required here because your view module gets loaded before your urls, so they are not available yet.